# Appending data to json file in C: append stops after reaching a certain number of entries

Tags: c

The objective is to append entries to a `json` file. Here is a demo program similar to my application. When I run the below code, after appending 1020 entries, the append stops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ENTRIES_PER_LOG 10000

static int packet_count = 0;
static char filename[100] = "output.json";

int write_json(const char *json){
    packet_count++;
    // create file if it doesn't exist
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
       fp = fopen(filename, "w");
       if (!fp)
           return 0;
       fputs("[]", fp);
       fclose(fp);
    }

    // add the document to the file
    fp = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    if (fp)
    {
       // check if first is [
       fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
       if (getc(fp) != '[')
       {
           fclose(fp);
          return 0;
       }

       // is array empty?
       int is_empty = 0;
       if (getc(fp) == ']')
           is_empty = 1;

      // check if last is ]
       fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_END);
       if (getc(fp) != ']')
       {
           fclose(fp);
           return 0;
       }


       // replace ] by ,
       fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_END);
       if (!is_empty)
           fputc(',', fp);

       // append the document
       fputs(json, fp);

       // close the array
       fputc(']', fp);
       fclose(fp);
       return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        char json[100] = "";
        sprintf(json, "{\"a\":%d}", packet_count);
        printf("%s\n", json);
        write_json(json);
    }
}
```

In each run, it stops after appending 1020 entries in the `json` file. But the program runs till the end of for loop. Restarting the process starts appending to the file, but again it appends only 1020 entries and then, it stops appending.I have no clue on why it stops. Any help or directions on why append stops after certain number of entries will be thankful.

Comment: Opening/closing the file for each entry is not a very good idea. Other than that, use debugger to see what it is doing in the iterations it does not write anything.

Comment: What makes you claim it stops after 1020 entries?

Comment: I used an [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) and it stopped after 124 entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is leaking resources. That is each call to `write_json` is opening the file twice, while leaking the descriptor for the first open. After a certain amount of the calls it is reaching the limit of allowed opened files.

```
 // create file if it doesn't exist
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r"); // <------ 1st open
    if (!fp)
    {
       fp = fopen(filename, "w");
       if (!fp)
           return 0;
       fputs("[]", fp);
       fclose(fp);
    }

    // add the document to the file
    fp = fopen(filename, "rb+");   // <------ Second open overwriting `fp`
```